# Recursive Anti-Symmetrical Counter SML

Tags: list, recursion, sml, symmetric

This is an anti-symmetrical recursive function that will take a list of pairs If the list is anti-symmetrical then an empty list will return and if the list is symmetrical it will return only the two pairs that are symmetrical.

Here is an example output.

```
val antisymmetric_rel = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,4), (5,9), (10,9), (0,0)];

antisymmetricCounterEx(antisymmetric_rel);
(* [] *)

val not_antisymmetric_rel = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,4), (5,9), (10,9), (9,5)];
(* [((5,9),(9,5))] *)
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
  fun antisymmetricCounterEx([]) = [] 
    | antisymmetricCounterEx(relation) =
        let 
          fun testOne((a, b), []) = []
            | testOne((a, b), (c, d)::rest) =
                (if (not (a = d)) orelse testOne((b, d), rest) ) then []
                else [(a, b)] @ testOne((c, d), rest);

          fun testAll([]) = [] 
            | testAll((a, b)::rest) = 
                testOne((a, b), relation) @ testAll(rest);
        in 
          testAll(relation)
        end;
```

I am getting errors that I cannot understand but it seems that the type and operands are ok.

Comment: In `(not(a=d)) orelse testOne((b,d),rest) )` the left operand is a boolean and the right is a list.

Comment: I still get a similar error. I added another code that checks if the element is related and put orelse isrelated() to keep the same boolean operand.

Comment: There's also a pair of stray parentheses in `(if  ... ) then ... else ...`.

Comment: Also note that: `[(a, b)] @ testOne((c, d), rest)` is the same as `(a, b) :: testOne((c, d), rest)` but the latter is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's clean up your code a bit.

1. We can remove the parentheses here: `(if (not (a = d)) orelse testOne((b, d), rest) ) then []` which break the syntax, as well as generally eliminate extraneous parens throughout the code.
2. `not (a = d)` can be written as `a <> d`
3. `[(a, b)] @ testOne((c, d), rest)` is replaced with `(a, b) :: testOne((c, d), rest)`

```
fun antisymmetricCounterEx([]) = [] 
  | antisymmetricCounterEx(relation) =
    let 
      fun testOne((a, b), []) = []
        | testOne((a, b), (c, d)::rest) =
          if a <> d orelse testOne((b, d), rest)  then []
          else (a, b) :: testOne((c, d), rest);

      fun testAll([]) = [] 
        | testAll((a, b)::rest) = 
          testOne((a, b), relation) @ testAll(rest);
    in 
      testAll(relation)
    end;
```

This still fails because as pointed out in comments `testOne` returns a list:

```
fun testOne((a, b), []) = []
```

But it's used in a boolean context.

Really what you have is a filtering exercise. You need to filter for any pair that has a symmetrical counterpart in the list. However, you need to account for pairs that are symmetrical with themselves, like `(4, 4)` and `(0, 0)`.

To aid with this, let's write a `list_count` function that can count the number of elements in a list that fulfill a predicate function.

```
fun list_count _ [] = 0
  | list_count f (x::xs) = 
    (if f x then 1 else 0) + list_count f xs;
```

We can now use `List.filter` and `list_count` to achieve the desired result.

```
fun sym_pairs(pairs) =
  List.filter 
    (fn (a, b) => 
       let
         val c = list_count (fn (c, d) => a = d andalso b = c) pairs 
       in
         if a = b then c > 1
         else c = 1
       end) 
    pairs;
```

Now:

```
sym_pairs([(1,2), (2,3), (4,4), (5,9), (10,9), (0,0)]);
```

Yields: `[]`. And:

```
sym_pairs([(1,2), (2,3), (4,4), (5,9), (10,9), (9,5)]);
```

Yields: `[(5, 9), (9,5)]`.